# Swift server-side vapor: How to download file to disk?

Tags: swift, server, request, client, vapor

I want to download multiple files in swift vapor. Some files have to be downloaded to disk and some should be just in-memory. For some i need to specify http-headers.

I know of the `ClientRequest` which can be used to get the result as an in-memory string. With it i can also specify the headers. Like this:

```swift
let request = ClientRequest(
    method: .GET,
    url: URI(string: url),
    headers: headers
)
let response: ClientResponse = try app.client.send(request).wait()

guard
    var body = response.body,
    let rawBytes = body.readData(length: body.readableBytes),
    let decoded = String(data: rawBytes, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
else {
    return nil
}
```

Is there also a way of downloading a file directly to disk? Or piping it to disk?
If the file is too large i don't want to have it in-memory all at once. Especially when it's not necessary.

I'm aware that I can call `curl`/`wget` from swift, but that is not what i'm after..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some searching i noticed this:

[async-http-client](https://github.com/swift-server/async-http-client#file-downloads) is a dependency of [vapor](https://docs.vapor.codes/basics/client/)

therefor it can directly be used to download a file:

```swift
let client = HTTPClient(eventLoopGroupProvider: .createNew)
let request = try HTTPClient.Request(
    url: "https://swift.org/builds/development/ubuntu1804/latest-build.yml"
)

let delegate = try FileDownloadDelegate(path: "/tmp/latest-build.yml", reportProgress: {
    if let totalBytes = $0.totalBytes {
        print("Total bytes count: \(totalBytes)")
    }
    print("Downloaded \($0.receivedBytes) bytes so far")
})

client.execute(request: request, delegate: delegate).futureResult
    .whenSuccess { progress in
        if let totalBytes = progress.totalBytes {
            print("Final total bytes count: \(totalBytes)")
        }
        print("Downloaded finished with \(progress.receivedBytes) bytes downloaded")
    }
```

or like this

```swift
let request = try HTTPClient.Request(url: url, method: method, headers: headers)
let delegate = try FileDownloadDelegate(path: filePath)
_ = try client.execute(request: request, delegate: delegate).wait()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `async` function `bytes(from:delegate:)` from [UrlSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767351-bytes). It will give you a `AsyncBytes`.
Then you can write the bytes with a `FileHandle`

```swift
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["x":"y"]
let session = URLSession(configuration: config))
guard let url = URL(string: "http://example.com") else { fatalError("bad url") }
let (bytes, response) = try await session.bytes(from: url)
for try await character in bytes.characters {
   // Write Character to FileHandle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you'll need to drop down to `app.http.client` to use the `AsyncHTTPClient`, and then you can use the [streaming APIs](https://github.com/swift-server/async-http-client/tree/main#streaming) to save each check to a file without loading the whole file into memory.

You can then use Vapor's `FileIO` so save each chunk. See [here](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/main/Sources/Development/routes.swift#L198) for an example when doing uploading but you can apply the same logic to streaming from an API